# Do browsers optimize js code?

Tags: javascript, browser, graph

I've faced a weird problem, I wrote a force-directed graph layout script, and I'd like to see how the node placement happens in near real-time, that's why I'm calculating forces and redrawing elements only once on each screen refreshment using requestAnimationFrame (though I know it would be more efficient to calculate layout in one step using 'while' statement and draw it immediately).

So the problem is that when it happens first time after I reload the page it works the way I want it to work: for example 60-nodes graph calculation takes 8879ms and I'm able to see how all the nodes move to their final destination, but when I'm trying to rebuild the same graph without page reloading each consequent calculations happens much faster:

```
8879ms
5797ms
4649ms
4330ms
3923ms
....
3046ms
....
etc
```

So the nodes become stable almost instantly. The difference for the small graphs could be as huge as 10-20 times!
16-nodes graph:

```
3041
1583
1101
818
660
551
524
436
373
360
352
305
167
```

After I reload the page the process repeats. So I'm wondering why does it happen in the first place (do the browsers cache and optimize the code somehow?) and how to avoid it if it's possible. Tried it in IE, FF and Chrome with the same results.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, JS engines optimize the code. But.. Where's your code ?

Comment: Don't see how the code itself could help to answer the question. What part of the code are you interested in?

Comment: During loading a page lots of other things need to happen. Probably the JS thread gets less CPU time in this period.

Comment: What do you mean by "*avoid it*"? That it starts slow? That is becomes faster? Neither is possible. Show us your code if you're looking for improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they did, and that's the key to imporve js engine performance.

I've heard that google chrome's V8 js engine compiles JavaScript to native machine code, and this is why chrome is so fast.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)

It seems that your problem is about your knowledge of javascript, no the browser, javascript sometimes is tedious and hard to completely master. Sometimes your code simply execute without  following the order as you expected.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this for some particular cases?

Comment: May be you need some specific time control, explicitly let the process wait for a certain time with some function like setInterval().

Answer (score 0):

Never count on calculation to be slow enough that you can see the results. Sooner or later, you always end up proven wrong. `requestAnimationFrame` is for animations that need to draw as smoothly as possible, and might give you arbitrary FPS. If you need to limit the rate that something happens, use `setInterval`, or use `requestAnimationFrame` but lower the amount you move each node by proportionally to the time that passed since the last frame.

Comment: I was pretty sure that requestAnimationFrame refreshes the screen with some constant intervals, but it seems that I was wrong about it. I will give setInterval a try and get back here with the results.

Comment: Nope, setInterval works even worse :) First try - 308ms, second - 22ms! I'm not sure how it's possible if the interval is obviously constant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Chrome has their V8 engine, Firefox has spidermonkey and I believe Safari has JavaScriptCore in their WebKit framework. In addition, Firefox has support for asm.js, a subset of javascript which can get compiled down from C/C++ code, and is recently used in the awesome javascript port of the Unreal Engine

http://www.unrealengine.com/html5/

So, yes- substantial resources go into optimizing javascript execution, and performance varies by browser a bit. The new ones generally work gloriously. (It's actually a tricky process to optimize js because it's such a heavily dynamic language- objects can change character and properties can mutate at any time. This difficulty is partly the rationale behind Google's 'Dart' language:

https://www.dartlang.org/support/faq.html)

Having said that, if you write a really inefficient while loop, there's only so much the browser can do.

Comment: Ok, maybe there is a way to make a browser think that the script/page is new without actually reloading the page?

Comment: Well, you can investigate turbo-links. You may have seen them in some Google+ pages. The idea is that it loads new webpages by ajax instead of actually loading a new html page in the browser. The advantage is that is eliminates the need for the browser to download and re-compile all the javascript again, and this is a substantial performance benefit.